# Update remote File using Eclipse's RSE Plugin

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've installed the Remote System Explorer Plugin for Eclipse and set up a SSH connection to our development server using public key authentication and a custom Port (not sure if any of these customisations relate to the problem).

However browsing the file system works great and I can even create folders and files. E.g. /tmp/foo/bar.txt but I can't figure out to "push" changes I've did to the server.

So my problem is I open a file, write some text and save it in Eclipse. The asterisk next to file names vanishes (indicating it's save) and if I close an re-open the file in Eclipse the changes are present. But they're not visible on the server. E.g. doing changes to a .html file won't show any changes in the web browser or cat bar.txt (mentioned earlier) produces an empty output.

Creating folders or files is working as intended but updates to file contents are not shown up on the remote system though they're persist in Eclipse.

Is there some button I'm missing to update my "local" changes to the "remote server". Can I even get rid off all this caching? As we're working in a Team it's crucial our Files are always up to date and having some extra caching would definitely spoil all the fun :(

My IDE configuration is like that :
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a handle to the [IFileService](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.rse.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/rse/services/files/IFileService.html) that is hosting the file ... this gives you the ability to upload files.

Comment: Sorry, but could you be more specific?  Can this be done via the IDE?  Or does it have to be done programatically?

Comment: Programatically ... you would have to create a plug-in to interact with the IFileService